# Нужно ли ставить тире на месте пропущенного слова «есть»?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

«У Маши мало игрушек и наклеек. Зато у неё **(есть)** обилие заколок».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наличие или отсутствие тире в подобного рода предложениях будет зависеть от интонации, которую хочет передать автор, поэтому возможны оба варианта.

***Зато у неё — обилие заколок.

Зато у неё обилие заколок.***

[**Тире в неполном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93) (Розенталь):

> 1. Тире ставится **при наличии паузы** в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым): ...*А в двери — бушлаты, шинели, тулупы…* (М.); *За ночным окном — туман* (Бл.); *Олимпийский огонь — на нашей земле!* (Газ.)...
>    **При отсутствии паузы** тире в эллиптическом предложении не ставится: *А в доме стук, ходьба…* (Гр.); *Вдруг передо мною рытвина глубокая* (Л.); *Скрип шагов вдоль улиц белых, огоньки вдали* (Фет); *У Хохла пожар!* (М. Г.); *Револьвер на стол!* (К. Т.)...

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, постановка тире в неполных и эллиптических предложениях определяется именно с помощью интонационного анализа,  и недаром Розенталь уделяет этому так много внимания. Даже в БСП, где интонация является основным средством связи, можно еще худо-бедно обойтись одними правилами, но здесь задача имеет только интонационное решение.